# Suggested pattern for "inheriting but extending Enum list of options"

Tags: python, enums

I have a `Task` class which runs and then parses result data to determine the `Task`'s `task_status`. The `task_status` can be things like `'SUCCESS'` or `'FAILURE'`. I am choosing to represent these possible task statuses with an Enum. This is fine. However, I am subclassing `Task` and the more specialized classes should have more task statuses available to them. For example a `TaskWithRetry` should also have available a `RETRY` status. What is a nice way to realize this?

Example code:

```
from enum import Enum

class TaskStatus(Enum):
    SUCCESS = 'SUCCESS'
    FAILURE = 'FAILURE'

class Task:
    ...
    def run():
        ...
        self.data = ...
        self.task_status = self.parse_data(self.data)

    def parse_data(self, data)
        if data is good:
            task_status = TaskStatus.SUCCESS
        elif data is bad:
            task_status = TaskStatus.FAILURE
        else:
            raise ValueError('Cannot parse data')
        return task_status

class TaskWithRetry(Task):
    def parse_data(self, data)
        if data is good:
            task_status = TaskStatus.SUCCESS
        elif data is bad:
            task_status = TaskStatus.FAILURE
        elif data is kind of bad:
(*)         task_status = TaskStatus.RETRY
        else:
            raise ValueError('Cannot parse data')
        return task_status
```

The issue here is that line `(*)` will fail because `RETRY` is not in `TaskStatus`. My possible solutions are:

- Add `RETRY` into `TaskStatus` `Enum`. The problem with this is that, suppose I am working on `SubTask A`. I don't want to see `TaskStatus.X,Y,Z` related to `SubTask D`.
- Create a dedicated `SubTaskStatus` `Enum` for each subtask. This will result in a lot of duplication of the shared `SUCCESS` and `FAILURE` options that any `Task` can have and it is extra work/complexity needed to define any new `SubTask`.
- My first idea was to subclass `TaskStatus` into `SubTaskStatus` so that I could inherte `SUCCESS` and `FAILURE` but add new options as needed for each `SubTask`, but I learned that, for presumably good reasons, you can't subclass `Enum` children like that and then define new fields.
- If I abandoned the `Enum` approach I could define strings like `SUCCESS = 'SUCCESS'` at the module level. Then I could define new strings like `RETRY = 'RETRY'` at the appropriate place in the module. This would be similar to adding all possibilities to the `TaskStatus` enum but at least the new statuses would be proximate to the relevant classes.
- Like the previous idea but maybe better: task statuses could be defined as class attribute strings. That way `self.SUCCESS` would be defined for any child of `Task` and new statuses would be class attributes on children. This idea seems ok, but how do I explicitly indicate that these strings are meant to be possible task statuses?

Also bear in mind that this code will be used in such a way where users/devs are regularly subclassing Task and it will need to be pretty simple to understand how to add new tasks statuses for a particular new `Task` as needed.